# Checking if Debugger is present in c++ dll (loaded in C++/CLI wrapper)

Tags: c++, dll, command-line-interface, release-mode, debug-mode

I'm checking if a debugger is present in my c++ dll with method

```
if(IsDebuggerPresent()) // set dll name to debug
```

When I load this dll in my C++/CLI wrapper (debug mode in VS) the method always returns false (release) -> why is it so? (or which code I need to determine this information)

Thank you for your help!

greets leon22

Comment: Is unmanaged debugging option selected in debugger?

Comment: Wait, are you saying "it is false in debug build" (i.e. wrapper is built as "debug") or "it is false when _run from_ the debugger"? Those are different things.

Comment: That was the solution: just enable unmanaged debugging ! (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the solution: just enable unmanaged debugging ! (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) returns true if a debugger is attached to your application. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I know this method, but this is only for managed .net code -> I'm into an native C++ dll (loaded from .net C++/CLI wrapper)!